# prometheus rule failing with "many-to-many matching not allowed"

Tags: prometheus

I have an out of the box kube-prometheus v0.3 setup where one of the rules:

```
alert: KubeletTooManyPods
expr: max
  by(node) (max by(instance) (kubelet_running_pod_count{job="kubelet"}) *
  on(instance) group_left(node) kubelet_node_name{job="kubelet"}) / max by(node)
  (kube_node_status_capacity_pods{job="kube-state-metrics"}) > 0.95
```

is triggering the following error:

> found duplicate series for the match group {instance="10.0.1.151:10250"} on the right hand-side of the operation: [{**name**="kubelet_node_name", endpoint="https-metrics", instance="10.0.1.151:10250", job="kubelet", metrics_path="/metrics", namespace="kube-system", node="ip-10-0-1-151.eu-west-1.compute.internal", service="prometheus-operator-kubelet"}, {**name**="kubelet_node_name", endpoint="https-metrics", instance="10.0.1.151:10250", job="kubelet", metrics_path="/metrics", namespace="kube-system", node="ip-10-0-1-151.eu-west-1.compute.internal", service="kubelet"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side

What is wrong with this rule?

Answer (score 6):

You should inspect services in kube-system namespace, there can be duplicated services, "prometheus-operator-kubelet" and "kubelet" in your case.

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction to Join:**

Join is of the format

<Leftside Query><operator> on/ignoring group_left/group_right <Rightside Query>

Here the query is

```
max
  by(node) (max by(instance) (kubelet_running_pod_count{job="kubelet"}) *
  on(instance) group_left(node) kubelet_node_name{job="kubelet"}) / max by(node)
  (kube_node_status_capacity_pods{job="kube-state-metrics"}) > 0.95
```

The join part of the query is `max by(instance) (kubelet_running_pod_count{job="kubelet"}) * on(instance) group_left(node) kubelet_node_name{job="kubelet"}`

```
max by(instance) (kubelet_running_pod_count{job="kubelet"}) ======> Left query
* ==========> Operator
on(instance) =========> what columns should be considered for join
group_left(node) ==========> How to group (Many is allowed on which side)(column node added to left metric)
kubelet_node_name{job="kubelet"} =========> Right query
```

Let us suppose these are rows returned by each metric

kubelet_running_pod_count

```
Row#1: {x=400, y=1, instance=1.1.1.1} 2       
Row#2: {x=500, y=2, instance=1.1.1.1} 5 
Row#3: {x=400, y=3, instance=2.2.2.2} 1 
Row#4: {x=500, y=4, instance=2.2.2.2} 7
```

kubelet_node_name

```
Row#1: {y=1, instance=1.1.1.1} 1       
Row#3: {y=3, instance=2.2.2.2} 1
```

Now rows 1,2 from kubelet_running_pod_count are multiplied (*) by row 1 from kubelet_node_name and rows 3,4 from kubelet_running_pod_count are multiplied (*) by row 3 from kubelet_node_name. This is allowed as group left is mentioned and the instance (column mentioned in on clause) is unique.

Now let us suppose the kubelet_node_name returns

```
Row#1: {y=1, instance=1.1.1.1} 1       
Row#2: {y=2, instance=1.1.1.1} 1       
Row#3: {y=3, instance=2.2.2.2} 1
```

Prometheus now gives error as mentioned in question as it doesnt understand row 1,2 on left should be operated by which row (either 1 or 2) on right.

Amazing examples on joins [here](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/prometheus-vector-matching/)

Solutions:
To get arround this

#1: Make sure that there is not duplicates on right side. This is either by picking metric which return unique value on the join column. or deduplication/dropping at prometheus configuration level (if multiple exporters returning same metric) (specify the exporter in query), etc.

#2: If #1 not possible expand the join columns ie in above case change the on clause from on(instance) to on(y, instance) to get uniqueness.

#3:
Assumption: The purpose of this join is to attach label 'node' to metric kubelet_running_pod_count (not concerned about the value it is anyways 1 for kubelet_node_name). In this specific scenario we can follow below solution.

Eliminate duplicate rows on right by wrapping the right side query kubelet_node_name{job="kubelet"} with group clause. E.g below

```
max
  by(node) (max by(instance) (kubelet_running_pod_count{job="kubelet"}) *
  on(instance) group_left(node) group(kubelet_node_name{job="kubelet"}) by (instance)) / max by(node)
  (kube_node_status_capacity_pods{job="kube-state-metrics"}) > 0.95
```